# How to compare the similarity between two particle size distributions?

Tags: statistical-significance, similarities

I have been trying to find an answer for this question.
I have two soil particle size distributions, which both have 4 categories.
I should do a statistical test to find out if they are statistically different.

Chi-squared test would be good for this kind of task. 
However, since the particle size distributions are mean values and percentages, the chi-squared test should not be used for this kind of task (since the test allows only count values or frequencies).

Here is an example table:

Clay; Silt; FineSand; CoarseSand

Set 1;    50;    20;     20;       10

Set 2;    45;    25;     15;       15

The values are percentages and sum to 100%.

What do you think, what kind of test would be good for this kind of task?